# Matlab: equivalent of R's matrix multiplication (A %*% B)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Working in Matlab with time-homogenous Markov Chains and looking to figure out how I can perform matrix multiplication in Matlab for matrix A, similar to R's matrix multiplication, i.e., `A %*% A`.  It would be even better if I could perform `A^n` instead for a given n instead of having to use `A %*% A %*% A`, when `n = 3`, for example.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand—you can already do that. In fact, you've given the exact operator. `A = [2 0; 0 1]; A^3` or `A = [2 0; 0 1]; A * A * A` are both valid MATLAB code.

Comment: Ah Arya was a bit faster :) For Matlab vs R i can highly recommend this document: http://www.math.umaine.edu/~hiebeler/comp/matlabR.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can raise a Matrix to a power in MATLAB:

`A ^ n = A * A * A * ... * A`

Actually MATLAB uses pretty sophisticated algorithms behind the scene to accelerate this.
For example, if the Matrix is diagonalizable, MATLAB will use that to accelerate the calumniation.